# characteristics of different bit sequences over network

Tags: layer1

Do different sequences of bits exhibit different characteristics when sent over a network.

For example, does one sequence of bits have a higher error rate than another sequence? If there are differences, are they true in theory and in practice?

Comment: To prevent that, bits are encoded into symbols that are sent over the medium. Different media and protocols use different encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean user or payload bits. The physical layer uses *line codes* and *scrambling* to prevent transmission problems for certain bit pattern.

Sometimes, this is less successful (early 100BASE-TX) but usually the encoding takes good care of that problem - so no, the user bit sequences don't (or shouldn't) matter.

However, in very special cases, specially crafted "[killer packets](http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/news/5_7.htm)" can cause too much DC energy to be generated for the PHY to handle, so the transmission breaks down.